If the pages window is too narrow, pages info covers up the buttons in InDesign
I've just updated InDesign to the latest version, and now the text at the bottom of the Pages window is blocking the buttons below it (see images attached)


As you can see, when making the Pages window narrow, as I have always done, the info now blocks the buttons. Is there a setting to correct this, or is it a bug? It's never happened before, and only since I recently updated InDesign.

I believe this qualifies as a UI bug. You may need to file a bug report with Adobe if you wish to see it repaired.
